# How do I add a condition statement to the input data?

Tags: python, list, input

In this program 10 inputs are taken into a list and now need to add a condition that is the input data should be between -20 and +20 and if the value is anything beyond the condition an exception error is to be shown. How do i do it ?

```
CODE:
lst=[]
print("Enter 10 numbers : \n")
for i in range(0,10):
    lst1=int(input())
    lst.append(lst1)

print("\nThe entered list is : ",lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test the value of `lst1`, then raise an exception if it falls outside your valid range:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    lst1=int(input())
    if lst1 < -20 or lst1 > 20:
        raise ValueError("Out-of-range value entered")
    lst.append(lst1)
```

Sample output:

```
1
2
-30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise ValueError("Out-of-range value entered")
ValueError: Out-of-range value entered
```

Comment: Thank you so much but now can i add an exception statement and make the further program to continue  ?